# What is the unit of the return values (coefficients) of an FFT?

Tags: audio, fft

My application performs an FFT on the raw audio signal (all microphone readings are 16bit integer values in `values`, which is 1024 cells). It first normalizes the readings according to the 16bit. Then it extracts the magnitude of the frequency 400Hz.

```
int sample_rate = 22050;
int values[1024];
// omitted: code to read 16bit audio samples into values array

double doublevalues[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    doublevalues[i] = (double)values[i] / 32768.0; // 16bit
}

fft(doublevalues); // inplace FFT, returns only real coefficients

double magnitude = 400.0 / sample_rate * 2048;
printf("magnitude of 400Hz: %f", magnitude);
```

When I try this out and generate a 400Hz signal to see the value of `magnitude`, it is around 0 when there is no 400Hz signal and goes up to 30 or 40 when there is.

What is the unit or meaning of the `magnitude` field? It surprises me that it is larger than 1 even though I normalize the raw signal to be between -1..+1.

Comment: magnitude is just a double here, it is unrelated to the signal

Comment: OK, so how do I know how far this can go up? What's the range of possible values then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which FFT you are using, as there are different conventions on scaling. The most common convention is that the output values are scaled by N, where N is the size of the FFT. So a 1024 point FFT will have output values which are 1024 times greater than the corresponding input values. A further complication is that for real-to-complex FFTs people typically ignore the symmetric upper half of the FFT, which is fine (because it's conjugate symmetric) but you need to account for a factor of 2 if you do this.

Other common conventions for FFT scaling are (a) no scaling (i.e. the factor of N has been removed) and (b) sqrt(N), which is sometimes used for symmetric scaling behaviour of FFT versus IFFT (sqrt(N) in each direction).

Since sqrt(1024) == 32 it's possible that you're using an FFT routine with sqrt(N) scaling, since you seem to be seeing values of around 30 for for a unit magnitude sine wave input.

Comment: OK. I use a real FFT that returns only the real values. I tested that I'm getting a response at all. It is surprising to me to get values between 30 and 40 if I move the speaker next to the microphone. Should it not be much higher? 1024 would mean that the frequency is very loud in the original signal right?

Comment: You should read the documentation for your FFT routine, as each one is different.

Comment: does the magnitude I get out also depend on the volume of the signal?

Comment: Yes, the *magnitude* of the FFT output is directly proportional to the magnitude of the input (for any given frequency).

Comment: Paul R is correct. Also remember that after working out how the FFT scales wrt the input sample data, there's the question of how the input samples scale wrt the sound picked up by the microphone in the first place. And that will depend on the sensitivity of the microphone itself and the gain settings that are set up on the mobile/PC/whatever. So the magnitude of your 400Hz peak is going to be different on every single device. Your normalisation will  normalise the whole sound, not just the 400hz component.